# Resellerclub test domain register api call

Tags: php, api, dns

Getting error response while trying to register domain with resellerclub demo account, http://cp.onlyfordemo.net/reseller.

Response message: "ERROR You are not allowed to perform this action".

```
$apiUrl = 'https://test.httpapi.com';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl . '/api/domains/register.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'auth-userid=' . $resellerId . '&api-key=' . $apiKey . '&domain-name=' . $domain . '&years=' . $domain_list[$domain_name] . '&ns=glen669774.earth.orderbox-dns.com&ns=glen669774.mars.orderbox-dns.com&customer-id=' . $customerId . '&reg-contact-id='. $contacthash["registrantcontactid"] . '&admin-contact-id='.$contacthash["admincontactid"].'&tech-contact-id='.$contacthash["technicalcontactid"].'&billing-contact-id='.$contacthash["billingcontactid"].'&invoice-option='.$invoiceOption.'&protect-privacy=false');

$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[image: first Whitelist your ip]

First whitelist your ip in Resellerclub admin area for making  api call

http://heavens.co.in/resellerclub-api